# Реализация алгоритма power set

Tags: python, алгоритм

Ввод: [0, 1, 2]

Вывод: [[], [0], [1], [2], [0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1, 2]] (Порядок вывода массива не имеет значения)

Псевдокод:

[image: ыыыы]

Алгоритм действия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код на Python:

```
def power_set(array):
    result = [[]]
    for element in array:
        new_list = result.copy()
        for subset in new_list:
            subset.append(element)
        result += new_list
    return result

print(power_set(range(3)))
```

Вывод:
[[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]]

Проблема заключается в том что элементы списка ссылаются на одно значение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему произошла ошибка и как это исправить?

P. s. Прошу без импортирования модулей и только с двумя циклами

Comment: 1) можете привести, какой вывод ожидается? (также в виде списков) 2) Почему вы считаете, что "элементы списка ссылаются на одно значение"?

Comment: 1) Вывод: [[], [0], [1], [2], [0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
См. выше
2) Картинка 3

Answer (score 2):

```py
    result = [[]] # <- список списков
    for element in array:
        new_list = result.copy() # <- "мелкая" копия
```

Проблема в том, что у вас список списков, а `copy()` копирует только верхний слой, а всё, что в остальных слоях, продолжает указывать на прежнее место. Можно починить так:

```py
        new_list = [x.copy() for x in result] # <- копия глубиной 2 слоя
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь код заработал

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вашего кода в мелком копировании. Её можно избежать если уменьшить количество операций, которые меняют существующие массивы. Вместо `subset.append(element)` используйте `subset + [element]`. Результат обеих операций в чём-то одинаков, но вторая создаёт новый список, оставляя исходный без изменений:

```
def power_set(array):
    result = [[]]
    for element in array:
        result.extend([subset + [element] for subset in result])
    return result


print(power_set(range(3)))
```